# undefined reference error while building FFMPEG with NDK

Tags: android, c++, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I get this error while running build-ndk for  my  ffmpeg android project

```
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg-test-jni.so]
undefined reference to 'av_close_input_file'
undefined reference to 'av_find_stream_info'
undefined reference to 'av_open_input_file' 
undefined reference to 'avcodec_open'
```

Any solutions to get rid of this error ? I am  very new to ffmpeg and Android NDK

This is my Android MK file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#declare the prebuilt library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpeg-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg-2.5.4/android/armv7-a/libffmpeg.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ffmpeg-2.5.4/android/armv7-a/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := ffmpeg-2.5.4/android/armv7-a/libffmpeg.so
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm 
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := true

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#the andzop library

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=false
LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpeg-test-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg-test-jni.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg-2.5.4/android/armv7-a/include
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := ffmpeg-prebuilt
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -lm $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg-2.5.4/android/armv7-a/libffmpeg.so 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Any Pointers much appreciated 
Thanks!

Comment: LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm   is this actually linking the ffmpeg component libs?

Comment: nope , it is not really linking these libs , none of my ffmpeg libs are being recognized

Comment: for example of ffmpeg builds and links : https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/blob/master/Project/jni/Android.mk